# Bundler not loading the correct Gemfile

Tags: rubygems, bundler

I'm installing a Ruby CI server which is pulling my Rails git repos from Github and installing the gems with Bundler. The CI server has a Gemfile of itself (as it's also a Rails application). So far so good.

Now, I first run a bundle install after a new git pull, this works fine:

```
bundle install --gemfile=[..]/build_13/Gemfile --deployment
```

Next I list the installed gems and run rake (to run the test suite):

```
bundle list
bundle exec rake
```

That's where it's going worng. These last 2 commands load the Gemfile of the CI server which is different from the one installed a few seconds ago. This Gemfile is in a parent directory of the one I want to run so I suppose it first finds the "parent" Gemfile and forgets to look for the correct one.

Any idea how I can tell bundler to use the correct gems?

Comment: What are the contents of `./.bundle/config`?

Comment: Contents of my `./.bundle/config` file, does this help?
--- 
BUNDLE_FROZEN: "1"
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "1"
BUNDLE_PATH: [..]/bundle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it!

You can specify the Gemfile path as an environment variable:

```
export BUNDLE_GEMFILE=[..]/build_13/Gemfile
```

This will force Bundler to use the correct Gemfile. Thanks to Philippe Creux' [article](http://eggsonbread.com/2010/08/31/get-integrity-to-play-well-with-rails-3-and-bundler-1-0/) for pointing me in the right direction.

For future reference:

I'm using [BigTuna](http://bigtuna.appelier.com/) as my CI server and you'll need to add the statement above for each of the 'steps' to make it work.